# Overriding a distro-dependent Bash alias to act a bit different

Tags: alias, bashrc

In Ubuntu 16.04 I've added the following code to `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
alias ll="ls -la --group-directories-first"
```

I then rebooted.

<sub>Note: I used `/etc/bash.bashrc` because I needed all aliases whatsoever in the one file and available for all users.</sub>

---

My intention was to rewrite the "native" `ll` alias. Yet it wasn't changed; if I go to any dir that includes dirs and files, and I execute `ll`, I get a list **without** dirs being sorted above files. In other words.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ll` alias is defined in the default `.bashrc`.

An alias definition is a command. Bash is an imperative language, it executes commands one after the other. If there are multiple definitions for the same alias, the alias is redefined each time the shell executes one of the definitions. Thus the last definition wins.

When bash starts, it reads the system file `/etc/bash.bashrc` before the user file `~/.bashrc`. Thus a definition in `~/.bashrc` overrides any definition of the same alias in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. You can't (sanely) do anything in `/etc/bash.bashrc` to prevent a redefinition in `~/.bashrc`.

It doesn't make sense to impose convenience aliases on users. That's why `ll` is defined in `~/.bashrc` and not in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. So instead of putting your preferred definition in the system file, put it in your user file.

You could change the default `.bashrc` — that's `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. This file is copied to a user's home directory when the user's account is created. Changing a file in `/etc/skel` has no impact on already-existing accounts. But even that is not a good idea since what you're defining is a personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/bash.bashrc` applies to all users

`~/.bashrc` only applies to the user in which home folder it is.

So, if you change the alias `ll` in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and run `ll`, you will get the output of the alias defined in `~/.bashrc`, that is because `~/.bashrc` has precedence over the definition in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

To put it simply; Add **new** aliases in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but for rewrites, change `~/.bashrc`.

Edit:

If you really want to have it all in one file, remove all aliases from all `~/.bashrc` `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.profile` files of all users, then add all the aliases to `/etc/bash.bashrc` this will create a global alias configuration without any issues.

Edit 2:

Create or edit `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and copy your default `.bashrc` config, so that when you create a new user, there are no default aliases set.

Thank you @user4556274 for the edit suggestion.

Comment: @Benia, if you are the only user on your system, put all changes in `~/.bashrc`.  `/etc/bash.bashrc` is for settings that are to be shared among all users; then individual users may add additional (or override) settings in their personal `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Definitely DO NOT source `.profile` from `/etc/bash.bashrc` or any file with `rc` in the name.

Comment: Remove any `ll` aliases from `~/.bashrc` `~/.bash_profile` and/or `~/.profile` for all users on the machine.

Comment: I edited the answer, hopefully this will solve your question.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson, note the OP should also modify `/etc/skel/.bashrc` (or the equivalent) to remove any aliases which should not be added to a new user's `.bashrc` when a new user is added to the system.

Comment: I made an edit to my post about creating an `ll` function which I believe will eliminate the need to remove any aliases

Comment: For all aliases he wants to create, he will turn them into functions? That is terrible and unclean work.

Comment: How so?  I personally find functions to be much cleaner than aliases anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain `/etc/bash.bashrc` isn't a thing.  The file you are looking for is `$HOME/.bash_profile` OR `$HOME/.profile` Alternatively you could use `$HOME/.bashrc` but I think `profile` is the correct file for what you are trying to accomplish.

For an explanation of the difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` please see: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

To source `.profile` from `.bash_profile` add the following to your `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
  . ~/.profile
fi
```

Another potential option would be to make `ll` into a `function` inside `/etc/bash.bashrc` instead of an `alias` which I believe the function will take precedence over any aliases set with the same name.

```
ll () {

  ls -la --group-directories-first

}
```

Comment: Yea append that to the end of the file.

Comment: `/etc/bash.bashrc` is a thing for global settings.  However, if `ll` is redefined in the user's `.bashrc`, that will take precedence over the definition in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: @user4556274 On Mac and CentOS it's just `/etc/bashrc`

Comment: @Jesse_b, yes, but the OP identified the system as Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yea I found some info on it.  When I initially googled `/etc/bash.bashrc` it asked me if I meant `~/.bashrc` so I made an ass out of myself and assumed it was a typo.  This is a good thread about it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/815066/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-and-etc-bash-bashrc

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ubuntu but I do still think it should be in `.bash_profile` as `.profile` is normally for shells other than bash.  However you could also just source `.profile` from `.bash_profile` which a lot of people do for solidarity between login files.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: `. ~/.profile` is the same as `source ~/.profile`  Which essentially just executes all commands within that file in the current shell vs executing a script which runs all the commands in a new shell.

Comment: `/etc/bash.bashrc` is a thing on some systems including Ubuntu. It's an optional feature at compile time, there are popular distributions that omit it. Setting aliases in `.profile makes no sense (read the page you cite on the topic!). A function would not take precedence over an alias, it's the opposite.

Comment: I disagree.  `.profile` or `.bash_profile` are sourced at login so it would work fine and this is in fact where I define my aliases.